# Salesforce1 Opportunity Home Page URL

Tags: salesforce1-app

Does anyone know if Salesforce1 has a URL for the Opportunity Home Page?

When we click on our opporutunities tab on desktop, the URL looks like this:

```
https://company.my.salesforce.com/006/o
```

any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some more context about where exactly you will be using this link?

Comment: Within a Visualforce page redirect

Answer (score 0):

Within the URL of that Opportunity, You can append /one/one.app
i.e.

```
https://company.my.salesforce.com/006/o/one/one.app
```

Hope this helps...